# How can I pre-fill emails for GINInvite or google application invitation?

Tags: ios, google-app-invites

with google framework, Google/AppInvite

How can we add the list of emails for GINInvite object to send the invitation? I'm not getting any way to invite the list of emails I'm getting from my webApi

Is it possible to prefill users to send app invitation?
How?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the documentation for App Invites](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/ios/reference/api/protocol_g_i_n_invite_builder-p), there's absolutely no exposure of any e-mail or user information going in or out.  It looks like Google is being privacy-minded here and would prefer that users have total control as to how invites get addressed.

Comment: yes I have gone through the docs as well, So as per you there is no any way to prefill emails to whom I want to send the invitation? which are not in my google contact list. or even in my google contacts list. but user have to select manually correct?

Comment: that appears to be the situation in the current versions of GINInvite.

Comment: Same problem here. Google should really make it possible to send out app invites without the standard GUI, so it can be done directly within my own code and my own GUI.